# Creating a previously unexisting column in JOIN statement? mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For my site, I've created a search page where users can search for the phone model name or the manufacturers name -- but not both. Users can type "apple" and get a list of all Apple's phones, or they can type "3g" and get a list of all the phones with "3g" in their name.

But, if a user types, "apple iphone" or "htc evo", they get zero results because the manufacturer name and the phone name are in two different columns.

This is my search statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            o.id,
            o.label,
            o.manufacture_id,
            o.buyback_price,
            o.image_path,
            u.id,
            u.label
            FROM phone_models as o 
            LEFT JOIN manufactures as u ON o.manufacture_id = u.id
            WHERE o.label like \"%$searchTerm%\" OR u.label like \"%$searchTerm%\"
            order by o.label";
```

Is there a way to create a new column that has both data from `u.label` AND `o.label`?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try splitting the user's input into separate words and search both (or all if more than 2), in both columns. No need to create additional column.

Comment: You could also try something like: `WHERE (your condition) OR %\"$searchTerm%\" LIKE o.label  OR \"$searchTerm\" LIKE CONCAT(\"%\",u.label,\"%\") `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            o.id,
            o.label,
            o.manufacture_id,
            o.buyback_price,
            o.image_path,
            u.id,
            u.label
            FROM phone_models as o 
            LEFT JOIN manufactures as u ON o.manufacture_id = u.id
            WHERE CONCAT(u.label,' ',o.label) like \"%$searchTerm%\"
            order by o.label";
```

But replace spaces in your $searchTerm with %:

```
$searchTerm = str_replace(' ','%',$searchTerm);
```

Comment: I tried this with and without the str_replace and got nothing

Comment: try to change CONCAT(o.label,' ',u.label) to CONCAT(u.label,' ',o.label)

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED (thrice)

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            o.id,
            o.label,
            o.manufacture_id,
            o.buyback_price,
            o.image_path,
            u.id,
            u.label
        FROM phone_models as o 
        LEFT JOIN manufactures as u
          ON o.manufacture_id = u.id
        WHERE CONCAT(o.label,' ',u.label) 
              LIKE REPLACE('%$searchTerm%', ' ', '%')
           OR CONCAT(u.label,' ',o.label) 
              LIKE REPLACE('%$searchTerm%', ' ', '%')
        ORDER BY o.label
       ";
```